# How to parse a Typescript file using a Python script?

Tags: python-3.x, typescript

I have a scenario where I need to read ts files and get the methods with the respective code by using a Python script. I could do that manually by iterating the lines and detecting some keywords like `export function` or `function` but I was hoping that there is a cleaner/more simple way. I think doing it manually wouldn't be that simple to detect the end of the methods.

Running Python 3.11.2

I asked Bing Chat for this but the suggestion is using the typescript module for Python which I cannot use for some reason. I did `pip install typescript` without errors but with a deprecation message warning; on Import it says that the module could not be found.

This is the code that bing suggested:

```
import ast
import typescript

def get_functions(code):
    js_code = typescript.transpile(code)
    js_ast = ast.parse(js_code)
    functions = []
    for node in js_ast.body:
        if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
            functions.append((node.lineno, node.name, typescript.transpile(ast.unparse(node))))
    return functions
```

I'm very new with python, so If you can guide me with this it will be very appreciated.
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Bit.png)

Comment: Bing Chat probably made up random crap (including packages that don't exist). You shouldn't rely on these "AI solutions" when it comes to programming (at least, not in its current state). Have you considered coding this up in TypeScript instead of Python?

Comment: this is the typescript module:  https://pypi.org/project/typescript, but it does not looks like it does what you want it to do...

Comment: It is not possible to directly expose methods defined in a TypeScript file in Python because TypeScript and Python are different programming languages that are not directly compatible with each other...  however, you can achieve interoperability with a few different methods: ( communication protocol, message broker, or transpiler).